# 'MINIF' with the use of like "H123"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use a formula like below but for Min and Max - I know that there is no MINIF or MAXIF.

```
=AVERAGEIF(Sheet1!B:B,"*" & D3 & "*",Sheet1!C:C)
```

D3 contains "H123"
I can do above to work out the average of "H123"
I would like to work out the Min and Max using a similar formula

I have tried below without any luck

```
{=MIN(IF(B:B="*H123*",C:C))}
```

For example data can use below - data itself is non-sense but the principle is the same - Col A+D are irrelevant

```
Col B        |Col C
Marc-H123-123|12
KIH123LKA    |15
mjuH123mju   |10
```

Can this be done using a formula?

Answer (score 1):

So the expected answer is 10?  If so, this array formula worked for me (there may be other ways):

```
{=IF(FIND("H123",A1:A3,1),MIN(B1:B3))}
```

Should be pretty self-explanatory and seemed to work for me (make sure you change the references to suit your sheet).

If you'd like to keep your formula in the same format, you can also use

```
{=MIN(IF(FIND("H123",B1:B3,1),C1:C3))}
```

to get the same results.

If you want to use whole column references, try this:

```
=MIN(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B:B)),IF(FIND("H123",B:B,1),C:C)))
```

Not the least bit efficient and I wouldn't use this on a ton of columns or your worksheet will grind to a hault.  I think you're better off determining the range and setting the formula to only include the cells you need to calculate.

OK, last stab at it, honest:

```
=MIN(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B:B)),IF(NOT(ISERR(FIND("H123",B:B,1))),C:C)))
```

Comment: {=IF(FIND("H123",B:B,1),MIN(C:C))} used this but just got #VALUE

Comment: try it w/o whole column references.  I know you technically can do it that way in Excel 2007+, but I've found it to be not as reliable as you'd expect.  Whole column references do return a #VALUE error on my test sheet, but just including the necessary ranges returns the correct results.

Comment: {=IF(FIND("*61326*",B$2:B$1048576,1),MIN(C$2:C$1048576))} Still same error

Comment: sure, but you're including a TON of blank values, which is what is causing the error.  Just use the cells that have values in it.

Comment: @99moorem just added an option for whole column references.  See last edit.  Just keep in mind, it's *not* going to be very efficient!

Comment: @pnuts how so?  For cells that contain H123 in column C the minimum value in column D is 10, is it not? Please point out where I'm wrong, because I clearly don't understand the ask...

Comment: @pnuts I took it as wanting the MIN for C:C where B:B contains "H123" somewhere in that cell. Which my latest update seems to do.  I guess the OP can come back and clarify if I'm not understanding the ask correctly.